# When, why and how to use random slopes with three-way cross-level interactions in multilevel models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to estimate a hierarchical (random/fixed/mixed?) model with cross-level interactions and I can't wrap my head around if, how and where and why I should include random intercepts and slopes. To make things more complicated, the model is also some kind of "interrupted time series" model, i.e. I am interested in the effect of a specific event taking place.

To start with, a basic linear regression of my (simplified) model would basically look something like this. I am aware that the notation is not perfectly correct, but I hope you get the idea of the model:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 time\_var + \beta_2 time\_since + \beta_3 incident\_happened + \beta_4 incident\_type + \beta_5 group\_characteristic + \beta_6 incident\_happened*incident\_type + \beta_7 incident\_happened*incident\_type*group\_characteristic
$$

Now, it is clear that the basic linear regression is *not appropriate*, because the data is ***crossed*** (not nested). I identified the levels/variables like this:

**Level-1 variables (time specific variables):**

- `time_var`: a consecutive variable where 1 is the first occurence and 100 the last.
- `time_since`: a variable <0, if incident_happened == 0 and between 1 to 50 if incident_happened == 1
- `incident_happened`: a dummy indicating if the incident happened. This is actually the main effect I am interested in.

**Level-2 variables (incident specific variables):**

- `incident_type`: a dummy indicating if incident type is 0 or 1.

**Level-3 variables (group specific variables):**

- `group_characteristic`: a continous variable

As I said, the variable `incident_happened` is the effect I am interested in, but I assume that the effect is moderated by `incident_type` as well as the specific `group_characteristic` variable. Therefore, I am also interested in $\beta_6$ and $\beta_7$.

I am using the `lme4` package to estimate this model. My first intuition was to only allow for random intercepts like in this model:

```
random_intercept_model <- lmer(y ~ time_var + time_since + incident_happened*incident_type*group_characteristic + (1 | group_id) + (1 | incident_id), REML = FALSE)
```

This was the only way it would make sense to me because I thought: if I use my `group_characteristic` variable as a moderator, where is the sense in allowing the slope of e.g. `incident_happened` to vary by group? Because not every group can have the same characteristics (also, in my acutal model I have different group-characteristic variables included and the combination of these characteristics is not endless). So I assume, if there is a moderating effect of `group_characteristic`, then, allowing for random slopes by group will diminish or completely eliminate any significant coefficients in the model.

However, I just stumbled over [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/esr/article/35/2/258/5306121) where the authors state that it doesn't make any sense to use cross-level interactions withouth including a random slope. Therefore, I should actually include a random slope for `incident_happened` and `incident_type` (or maybe even for the interaction terms).

I am now going to try to formulate my questions:

**1. Question:** Do I really need random slopes in my model? If so, do I only need random slopes for `incident_happened` and `incident_type` or do I even need to allow for random slopes in the interaction terms?

**2. Question:** What is the appropriate way to implement this in R with the `lmer` function? My guess would be to allow for random slopes for `incident_happened` and `incident_type` for both, the second and third level and I guess the implementation would look something like this:

```
random_slope_model <- lmer(y ~ time_var + time_since + incident_happened*incident_type*group_characteristic + (1 + incident_happened | incident_id) + (1 + incident_type| group_id), REML = FALSE)
```

I am totally sorry for this awkward long text, but I am new to the hierarchical model game and also don't really understand what the different is to mixed models (I guess there are none?). Actually, at first the whole thing seemed to me like including interactions in a linear regression (but with different estimations to get robust standard errors), but the implementation in R confused me a lot.

Thanks for any answers!

**EDIT:**
Here is some example data:

```
    structure(list(group_id = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
    "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
    "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
    "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
    "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
    "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
    "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
    "group_3", "group_3", "group_3"), incident_id = c("incident_A", 
    "incident_A", "incident_A", "incident_A", "incident_A", "incident_A", 
    "incident_B", "incident_B", "incident_B", "incident_B", "incident_B", 
    "incident_B", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", 
    "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", 
    "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_A", "incident_A", 
    "incident_A", "incident_A", "incident_A", "incident_A", "incident_B", 
    "incident_B", "incident_B", "incident_B", "incident_B", "incident_B", 
    "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", "incident_C", 
    "incident_C"), y = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 25, 
    10, 26, 25, 27, 26, 1, 4, 4, 6, 4, 8, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 
    0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), time_var = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), time_since = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3), incident_happened = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), labels = c(`Pre Incident` = 0, 
    `After Incident` = 1), class = "factor"), incident_type = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
        group_characteristic_1 = c(56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 
        56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 
        61, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
        54, 54, 54, 54), group_characteristic_2 = c(49, 49, 49, 49, 
        49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 38, 
        38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 
        65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65), group_characteristic_3 = c(86, 
        86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 
        86, 86, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 
        94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just a couple of brief answers before you maybe edit your question a bit :) 1) Mixed models, multilevel models, and hierarchical models are used pretty interchangeably when we are talking about regression/generalized linear models. 2) You want random slopes when you want to investigate possible cluster-related differences between x and y, 3) you can also test whether including a random slope(/s) improves model fit and leave it out if it doesn't. 4) your first code has your random effects nested, the second has them crossed - you need to figure out which is appropriate.

Comment: 2) was meant to be "cluster-related differences in the relationship between x and y", in your case group-related and maybe incident -related.

Comment: @Sointu, thanks a lot for the answer! I just realized that I actually do have a crossed structure and not a nested structure, because "incident_1" is e.g. the same for group 1 and group 2! I am going to edit that in my question. Could you kindly guide me on what details I should include in my question to improve comprehensibility?

Comment: The question was reopened so it's open for answers, but it's a bit difficult to grasp your data structure from text - maybe you could post a snippet of your data or a small toy data frame with a similar structure? (as an aside, nested vs. crossed doesn't mean basic linear vs. multilevel - if you need to include random effects you need a multilevel model regardless of whether your random effects are nested or crossed)

Comment: @MikeHunter thank you! I know that the discussion evolves around the same topic that I am interested in, but I don't really know, if I draw the right conclusions from that. Because of what is stated there,  to me, the answers sound like "if the design justifies not to use random slopes, then don't use them". But this does not seem to be in line with what is stated in some of the scientific papers. However, including slopes leaves me with the "singular boundaries" warning and also, the model fails to converge (Which I also do not fully understand). I will be really happy about clarification.

Comment: I have no idea why you're getting these warnings. One way to approach them is to progressively build up the model from simple main effects to more complex by adding a parameter at a time. When the warnings appear, you'll know the source of the problem. The CV link also suggests an empirical heuristic to model choice wrt your question of adding random slopes. Build models with and without them and choose the best fitting model.